# Дергается position:fixed элемент

Tags: html, css, safari

По кнопке вызываю блок который имеет следующие стили

```
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: white;
padding: 30px;
z-index: 200;
overflow-y: auto;
```

в этом блоке есть div с кнопками у которого:

```
position: fixed;
margin-left: -15px;
height: 65px;
line-height: 65px;
bottom: 0;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
z-index: 200;
```

Проблема в том, что при прокрутке этого блока на айфоне этот div с кнопками дергается, пробовал разные методы фиксов, которые нашел в интернете, но что-то не помогло

html: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Удалось починить, добавил родителю

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
```